# How to use arrayformula to find and get data from only a certain, dynamic set of columns?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a table where my headers are dynamically generated from another source and can show up with any header values, in any order.

In the example below I've got the header values:

```
AA - BB - CC - ABBA - KK - VV
```

but it could just have well been:

```
CC - AA - QQ - YY
```

I don't know in advance which headers I will get, or how many.

My issue is that I want to sum all product values, using an array formula, where the column headers include for instance "*BB*".

So basically `=arrayformula(sumifs(C4:H1000,$C$3:$H$3,"*BB*"))`, if that had been a thing.

My closest guess is that I need to use a VLOOKUP of some sort, but since the index of the columns to get the data from isn't static I can't quite figure out how to solve it.

Desperate for help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4, MATCH("BB", 3:3, 0), 4)&":"&
   SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(4, MATCH("BB", 3:3, 0), 4), "4", "")))
```

[image: 0]

- first **`4`** is the start of the range for sum
- and the **`3:3`** is the row of headers